# Unexpected DateTime Range Scenario

Tags: c#, datetime

I hate dates. So I'm maintaining a project and came across an extension method which is a bit naive, but should do the trick in 99% of cases. It is checking a date range:

```
public static bool IsInRange(this DateTime dateToCheck, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    if (startDate <= endDate)
    {
        return dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck <= endDate;
    }

    return false;
}
```

So I have a situation which is baffling me. The return statement in the **if** scope is returning true when the **dateToCheck** is after the **endDate**. See the following screen grab for debugging values:

[image]

I considered the fact that they may have a different **DateTimeKind**, so I added the following statement to ensure they were both local:

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateToCheck, DateTimeKind.Local)
```

I am unable to reproduce this in a console application.

So I guess my question is, what the heck!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your `dateToCheck` variable closely, the year is 1917 which is obviously smaller than 2017(`enddate` year is 2017). So, it's working as expected as far as I can see.

Comment: ah so the problem is that I need glasses :)  I'm glad it was as simple as that. Thanks. A fresh set of eyes often helps.

Comment: @onefootswill : yeah, [sometime it happens.](http://iansommerville.com/software-engineering-book/case-studies/ariane5/)